# Opening a unit test in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: c#, microsoft-test-manager

I have a simple unit test project on Visual Studio 2012 Professional. I want to open this unit test using Microsoft Test Manager and run it. Is this possible? How do I do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Your unit tests should be run by your developers or as part of an automated build process rather than run manually. 

If the tests have not been run, ideally the code should not have been checked in.

What would the reasoning be for needing to run the test in isolation, outside of VS?

Comment: I think Microsoft Test Manager is for manual, end user type testing and is nothing to do with unit tests.

Comment: I understand my question is not practical but I need to know if this is possible. Can anyone give me any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: you could use mstest on the command line instead

Comment: @thumbmunkeys Thanks but I specifically want to run a unit test on MTM. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to run unit tests through MTM you need to have your project checked-in into the TFS.
You need to associate your manual tests created in MTM to your unit tests written.
Later in the MTM you need to create a plan, which will contain all you tests. Your also need to create build of your unit test script and associate it with the test plan. These build include the executable of you script, and need not to be updated unless your script is changed.

Follow some links you will find out how to create a build and more about MTM:

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/04/11/creating-a-build-definition-in-tfs.aspx

http://boldradius.com/blog-post/UwOLcQEAAJV04Pl3/automating-builds-with-tfs-build

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj635157(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191495.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191495.aspx